# Each loop based on store data bugs

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have a store to handle data, this data changes often.
`orderids` is a writable store, `orders` is an object where all the values are writable stores. Reason why I have them this way is to prevent updates to an order triggering updates for the other orders in the store. So I have them sep. I tried having them together and I have the same issue described below.

```js
import { orders, orderids } from '../store/orders.js';

const handler = (data) => {
    orderids.set(data.reduce((obj, order) => {
        obj[order.id] = order.id;
        orders[order.id] = writable(order);
        return obj;
    }, {}));
}
```

Orders.svelte

```js
<script>
    import Order from './Order.svelte';
    import { orderids } from '../store/orders';
    $: ids = Object.keys($orderids).sort((a, b) => a - b);
</script>

{#each ids as orderid, i}
    <Order {orderid} />
{/each}
```

Order.svelte

```js
<script>
    import { orders } from '../store/orders';
    export let orderid;
    $: order = orders[orderid];
    $: console.log('Update', $order.id); <----- Note here
    console.log('Load', $order.id); <----- and here
</script>

<div>
    <span>{$order.id}</span>
    ... a bunch of other stuff
</div>
```

Now the problem is that when I modify the orderids store by deleting or adding keys/values, sometimes half the html of a specific order will be wrong. I noticed that the reactive console log shows the new (correct) order data, but the regular console.log doesn't run sometimes. Anyone know what's going on here ? Edit: the regular console.log only runs when an order id is added. When an order id is removed it doesn't run.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. I thought the data being passed (the orderid) would force a parity check but I actually had to pass the orderid again as key for the loop.

```js
            {#each ids as orderid (orderid)}
                <Order {orderid} />
            {/each}
```

This works, it triggers the regular console log and the reactive one.
Double passing the same thing (lol).